# double hung sash window, any way to prevent the top from being moved down?

Tags: windows, lock, fastener

I have double hung sash window, is there any way to prevent the top from being moved down?  A different style of window hardware possibly?

As of now I have a crecent style fastener in the middle, that will allow both the top and bottom to separate if unlatched.

They are wood sash windows, with a sash chord, and are approximately circa 1922.

Comment: Are these sashes vinyl?  Wood?  Are you looking for a permanent or temporary solution?

Comment: If they're wood, a temporary solution would be a sash spring bolt.

Comment: The usual solution is to drill a hole thru the upper sash into the (vertical sides) of the frame and stick a bolt in there.

Comment: you can use a shim or long dowel to wedge the top half open from the side, typically without blocking the bottom pane. You can also get locks that work on the top or bottom of the frame.

Comment: You could also use a sliding bolt latch on the top side edge of the upper frame, which wouldn't hinder the movement of the lower frame too much.

Comment: @IronEagle, updated question with window details.

Comment: Do you want to prevent any movement of the upper sash at all when the lower sash is raised, or do you want to restrict the movement of the sashes to a limited opening?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri, trying to keep the upper window stuck closed, so that only the bottom can freely move up and down.

Comment: Be careful if a small child can fall out the lower portion. Often we secure the bottom and let the top open.

Comment: If the window is located in a bedroom, make sure the opening meets “egress” requirements: 5.7 sq. Ft of opening with the width a minimum of 20” and minimum height is 24”. AND the sill cannot be more than 44” above the floor.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the previous owner of my house did to prevent the top sash from moving: Painted it liberally.  They will be sealed and painted shut.  You could also use caulking.  They make clear caulking too so it wouldn't be noticeable, or in case you have bare wood still that has survived unpainted for the past 98 years. As an added bonus that would keep the drafts down a little too!

Answer (score 1):

There are control devices that restrict the upper or lower sashes in double hung windows.

Here’s one style: [https://www.amazon.com/Double-Hung-Window-Opening-Control-Device/dp/B00XLV923G/ref=asc_df_B00XLV923G/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=198095900368&hvpos=1o18&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17549082380206194677&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9033075&hvtargid=aud-799728744414:pla-349410125410&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00XLV923G)

If you use these, they can be removed later.

Comment: Security latches prevent the window package from providing an opening larger than X. They restrict *both* sashes; the OP wants the lower sash to still be completely operable.